# How to modify shared folder permissions without a mandatory reboot

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have many Windows Server 2016 VM on a domain and most of them have Shared Folders. I have setup all of them to allow access by using local group. So each server i created custom group and set the different shared folders to allow the domain accounts in that group. So all i have to do in the future is connect to Server X and add the user Y to the group for the share Z. Very easy but 2 of those server are for developers and they are a Database server and a Web server which are production servers. Everytime i add someone to the group that person cannot connect to the shared folder until the server reboots.

Is there anyway to force an apply of the permission without having to reboot a server every single time ?

Comment: Normally reboot is not needed for such a change. Yet what you should do is use domain groups, not local groups (since all your servers are joined to domain). It's much easier, adding/removing group members from AD console, don't need to connect to each server. Perhaps that's why you need reboot, due to mixing local groups with domain users.

Comment: @Krackout I do not have access to domain groups. I am only allowed to manage my own server local groups.

Comment: Oh, I see. How are the rights set on directories, I mean, do you have the groups added to both share and security rights? Or perhaps `everyone` to security and restrict - add group - to share?

Comment: @Krackout Layout is pretty simple. Let's use just 1 server as example (they are all setup the same way). Lets say i have 2 shared folders, folder A and B. In that server local groups i have 4 groups (2 for each share) FullControl_A, FullControl_B,ReadOnly_A,ReadOnly_B. In the Server Manager under the file storage service i have setup the shared folder to use those groups and assign the right properly.

Comment: User group membership is evaluated when the user logs in. You should not need to restart the server. The users who get added to a group should simply log off and log back on.

Comment: @DawnBenton that is the first thing i thought to try and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Server service on Services.msc